# Exclude part of server name from Get-Snapshot PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, snapshot, powercli

What I am trying to do is get a list of VM Snapshots but exclude any snapshots that contain the VM naming convention of "ABCDE" and that the snapshots are over 3 days old and output it to a text file.

The script that I have thus far is the following but it is not excluding the servers that begin with "ABCDE".

```
# Get VM Snapshot Information excluding anything with HEIEPC

Get-VM | Where {$_.Name -ne "ABCDE"} |
    Get-Snapshot |
    Where-Object { $_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) } |
    Format-List | Out-File $Log -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for VMs with the *exact* name "ABCDE". To check for VMs whose name *begins* with "ABCDE" use the `-like` operator and a wildcard:

```
Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -notlike 'ABCDE*' } | ...
```

Make the pattern `*ABCDE*` if you want to exclude VMs with the substring "ABCDE" anywhere in their name (not just the beginning).

Comment: I am trying to get VM's that do not include "ABCDE" in the name.  That is getting names that have that naming convention